# How do I convert List[String] to List[ServerAddress]?

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala and am struggling with this silliest thing.

I have a List[String] and I want to parse the list and produce a new List[ServerAddress] (ServerAddress is a mongo thing.  What I am conceptually trying to do is convert a List of one Type to a different Type).  How do I do this?  My current attempt fails to populate my List[ServerAddress]

```
scala> val seeds: List[String] = List( "bobk-mbp.local", "bobk-mbp.local:27018" )
seeds: List[String] = List(bobk-mbp.local, bobk-mbp.local:27018)

scala> val serverAddrs = List[ServerAddress]()
serverAddrs: List[com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.ServerAddress] = List()

scala> for (seed <- seeds ) { new ServerAddress(seed) :: serverAddrs }

scala> serverAddrs
res12: List[com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.ServerAddress] = List()
```

Brother, could you spare a clue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this:

```
val serverAddrs = seeds.map((s) => new ServerAddress(s))
```

Edit:
Here is a more concise way:

```
val serverAddrs = seeds.map(new ServerAddress(_))
```

Comment: Isn't dot in your second example is wrong? By the way, if ServerAddress was a case class you could do just `seeds map ServerAddress`

Answer (score 4):

The `::` operator creates a new list rather than mutating the old one, so you're just creating a bunch of one-element lists and then discarding them.

The idiomatic way to do what you want in a functional language like Scala is just to map the list:

```
val serverAddrs = seeds.map( s => new ServerAddress(s) )
```

Answer (score 2):

See @Chuck's comments about `::`.

Here's a working `for` expression which is syntactic sugar for `map`:

```
scala> val seeds: List[String] = List( "bobk-mbp.local", "bobk-mbp.local:27018" )
seeds: List[String] = List(bobk-mbp.local, bobk-mbp.local:27018)

scala> class ServerAddress(address: String)
defined class ServerAddress

scala> for(seed <- seeds) yield new ServerAddress(seed)
res0: List[ServerAddress] = List(ServerAddress@1985828e, ServerAddress@c3e45b9)
```